# Unwanted (img) side padding in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

The problem only affects IE (Mine's 9) and as it's shown there are unwanted paddings on each side of the img tag.

Here's the CSS:

```
.imgclass {
    position:relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 60px;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    box-shadow: #666666 0px 0px 3px;    
    border-radius: 5px;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

And so far I've tried img>padding 0& img>display>block & img>vertical-align.

> Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2K4E.png

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know what's your problem, but opacity will not work in IE too.

Comment: Please provide more information, minimally the markup for the image and its closest ancestors. Tested alone, the CSS code does not trigger a problem like the one described. Moreover, in the screenshot, the colored areas around the image cannot be *padding* for the image, as they are outside the border of the image.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: Will do, the blue area around the image is not the padding I meant. The unwanted padding is actually those white, 1px vertical lines at each side of the image. (specially visible on the left)

Answer (score 1):

try adding the below to your imgclass in CSS

```
filter:alpha(opacity=90);
padding: 0;
```

and also check for padding in parent element

Comment: please show us this on a page and will definitely try to help.

Comment: Sorry but due to the project's schedule I had to adopt a different approach and changed the whole thing

Comment: sorry we could not help, I hope you get a quick answer the next time. Have you used jsfiddle? Use it often to give quick situations to folks here on SO

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a spin next time (which I'm sure comes soon enough)

Answer (score 0):

you can adde specifically that padding = 0

```
padding: 0;
```

also it would be good to know what class/attributes are applied to the div/element containing the image as if it is larger then padding may not be the issue? perhaps specify a specific width and height if you can to prevent css guessing.